# How to change/encrypt root password in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have three users in MySQL namely root, testuser1, testuser2. I want to encrypt the passwords for all three users when connecting to MySQL database by typing the following command in the terminal,

1. mysql -u root -p
2. mysql -u testuser1 -p
3. mysql -u testuser2 -p

It asks for password. At this point, How can I supply encrypted password or make it read from any file which may contain it?

There is an requirement in my project to encrypt all passwords for MySQL users. (I have also asked this question [in connection with MariaDB too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31957282/472495)).

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass an encrypted password on the mysql client command line and expect mysql to "understand" it.  At best, you can use an encrypted SSH session to for your mysql command line session.

You can certainly store encrypted passwords in a file or database, then decrypt them to connect.

But at some point, a password is going to have to be passed to mySql in plaintext.  You need to decide exactly:

1) how you're going to log on (from a command prompt?  Using a program or web server?

2) How exactly to secure the stored password (including, but not limited to, encryption) up to - and during - logon.

SOME ALTERNATIVES:

MySql also supports "Enterprise Logon" scenarios.  Perhaps one of these might offer a solution to your problem:

- [MySQL Enterprise Authentication](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/security.html)
- [Pluggable Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pluggable-authentication.html)

Finally, if you're using MySQL from an Application Server (for example, WebSphere), then instead of manually logging in with the "mysql" command line client), you can simply create a DataSource, and let the application server protect the DB username and password for you.

Comment: In addition to the answer, when you connect to mysql server remotely you do that normally through a secure network and channel like SSH, VPN connection etc. so the transmission of data between client an server will be encrypted that includes the user and password information. I will never do it from unsure connection or channel.

Comment: @maytham - that's exactly what I tried to say in the first paragraph.  Thank you for clarifying ... and we're in complete agreement :)