# How to encrypt root password in MariaDB?

Tags: encryption, mariadb

I have three users in MariaDB namely root, testuser1, testuser2. I want to encrypt the passwords for all three users when connecting to MariaDB by typing the following command in the terminal,

```
1. mysql -u root -p
2. mysql -u testuser1 -p
3. mysql -u testuser2 -p
```

It asks for password. At this point, How can I supply encrypted password or make it read from any file which may contain it?

There is a requirement in my project to encrypt all passwords for MariaDB users. (I have also asked this question [in connection with MySQL too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31956481/472495)).

Comment: As far as I know you cannot pass a hashed password to the `mysql` utility. However, I think you can specify connection details in a configuration file that you can protect using ordinary permissions (e.g. only make it readable by your user) - [see here](http://serverfault.com/questions/537582/mysql-without-password-prompt).